# Add JSON Object to angularjs $scope?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How do I inject my JSON Object in my angular $scope upon create()?

html:

```
<input type="text" class="title" placeholder="hold" ng-model="formData.text"/>
<input type="text" class="desc" placeholder="description" ng-model="formData.desc"/>

<button type="submit" class="btnCreate" ng-click="createRule();direction('front');go('/myrules')">CREATE
</button>
```

controller:

```
$http.get('/public/mdm/default.json').success(function (data) {

            $scope.data = data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        })

$scope.formData = {};

$scope.createRule = function () {
            Rules.create($scope.formData)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.formData = {};
                    $scope.rules = data;

                    // JSON please join my creation...
                });
        };
```

$scope.formData is the form poulation.  It is an Object so push() is out...

`$scope.formData[JSONObject] = $scope.data;` does not get added properly.

I feel this is a much simpler process than it currently appears to me.  Any direction is appreciated so Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question, warranting a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.formData.JSONObjectProperty = JSONObject;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: $scope.formData.data = $scope.data;

was the actual trick, but Im going to accept your answer for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.formData[JSONObject] = $scope.data;
```

JSONObject - I don't believe it's valid key for formData object hash.

have you tried to change it to vital name ?

```
$scope.formData["JSONObject"] = $scope.data
```

or

just do simple merge of objects, i.e. $scope.data -> $scope.formData

related question, I believe 
[AngularJS: factory $http.get JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file)

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

It is already a parsed as a js Object and I can get all data from within, the trouble is adding it to my scope.

Comment: I had an idea that maybe I could just wrap both $scope.data and $ scope.form Data in an array.  I have a factory that the rule is created within.  Ill update when back in front of my computer.