# AngularJS $http.get isn't working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a static json file at http:///test.json, which I can view in my browser just fine.

I'm trying to use $http.get to load that json file.  Here's my code in :

```
        testApp.run(function ($http) {
        $http.get("test.json")
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Yay!");
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Fail!");
            });
        });
```

Any suggestions?  Get is definitely being called as it's giving me the Fail alert.  This must be easy but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: What do you have in `status` variable in error handler?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging here. Check the status variable as @IvanNevostruev suggests, check the request/response in the Network tab of your web development tool, and make sure the JSON is valid.

Comment: Status is undefined :/

Comment: this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? Is the get request being made? What kind of response is coming back?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `/` on the URL for the GET method like this:

```
$http.get("/test.json")
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Yay!");
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Fail!");
            });
        });
```