# Ionic reading json file from web

Tags: json, angularjs, http, ionic-framework, factory

After trying what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file) question ask, I'm asking again how to retrieve data from web using AngularJS in the Ionic framework.
Basically, I do what the answer says:

```
.factory('Advices', function($http) {
   var advices = null;
   $http.get('http://myurl.myext/myfile.json').success(function (data) {
       advices = data;
   }).error(function(error) {
       console.log('error'); //even if there i print the error it prints nothing
   });

   //etcetera
```

How can I rescue that file from my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try to following code**

```
            var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
            app.controller('mainInfoFactory', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
              $http.get("http://myurl.myext/myfile.json")
              .success(function (response) 
              {
                $scope.advices = response;
              })
             .error(function(data) {
                alert("ERROR");
              });
            }]);
```

Here **myAPP** and **mainInfoFactory** are AngularJS application name and controller respectively.

For example : *ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainInfoFactory"*