# Load data from .json file into factory in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a factory which loads datas from array, or a selected element from this array. But if I move it to an external .json file, I just get errors - i am newbie to angular in all but trying hard, keep in mind ^^
So if I use the simple

```
$http.get('ports.json').success (function(data){
  var works = data;
});
```

code, I get "ReferenceError: works is not defined". And if I try the

```
$http.get('ports.json').then((portRes){
    var works = res.data;
});
```

I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" error. But that code in not a factory, on a whole different page works, so no idea what can be wrong now :/
Here is the .json filet, and @ the link, you can check the plunker.
Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/tMrJMjzc4pl7fQ1PIEiO?p=info

```
[
  {
    "Title": "Sprite",
    "subTitle": "",
    "Link": "sprite",
    "Thumbnail": "img/portfolio02.png",
    "Image": "img/ismont.png"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Pepsi",
    "subTitle": "Kristályvíz",
    "Link": "pepsi",
    "Thumbnail": "img/portfolio03.png",
    "Image": "img/sanofimont.png"
  }
]
```

EDIT: So I tried all what u wrote till now but nothing seemd to work... 
So I have thiw well-working factor now, which I want to transfer to an external .json file, to be very very clear for understand.

```
  portApp.factory("workFactory", function($http) {  
  var works = [
  {
      Title: "Sprite",
      subTitle: "",
      Link: "sprite",
      Thumbnail: "img/portfolio02.png",
      Image: "img/ismont.png"
  },
  {
      Title: "Pepsi",
      subTitle: "Kristályvíz",
      Link: "pepsi",
      Thumbnail: "img/portfolio03.png",
      Image: "img/sanofimont.png"
  }
  ];
  return {
      list: function() {
          return works;
      },
      selected: function(detPath) {
          selected = works.filter(function(work) {
              return work.Link == detPath;
          });
          return selected;
      }
  };
```

Comment: Since I cannot get it to work, no matte what I try from outer sites, still looking for a good Solution to get .json content into array inside a factory ^^

Answer (score 5):

You have lot's of problems with the Plunker you posted.

But the main problem was with this code:

```
portApp.factory("workFactory", function($http) {
        $http.get('ports.json').then((portRes) {
            var works = res.data;
        });
        return {
            list: function() {
                return works;
            },
            selected: function(detPath) {
                selected = works.filter(function(work) {
                    return work.Link == detPath;
                });
                return selected;
            }
        };
    });
```

Problems:
1. the `then` method expects a function. Change `(portRes)` to `function(portRes)`.
2. Doing `var works = res.data` creates a local var inside the callback function. You can't access it outside. Plus change `res` to `portRes`.
3.  Returning the `works` var wont work technically since it's a local var that isn't in the same scope. It wont work logically since the `$http.get` is an async process and you have no idea when it will finish.

**Edit:**
After you edited, I believe you need something like this(I didn't check this so there may be some errors but that's the way to do things):

```
portApp.factory("workFactory", function($http) {      
    var state = {
          works: null,

          list: function() {
              return this.works;
          },

          selected: function(detPath) {
              return this.works.filter(function(work) {
                  return work.Link == detPath;
              });
          }
    };

    $http.get('myJson.json').success(function(data) {
        state.works = data;
    }); 

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks amir, original question Updated. Please check :)

Comment: Thanks :) Now I think there is some json parsing error, because despite of what online json validators say, my json seems to be not legit :/
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token at Object.parse (native)"

Comment: Ok, updated the plunker itself and tried to investigate the scope what it gets back... I get a bigger object, which has subobjects, containing the wanted content. But.. how to access them? :s Sorry, but I can't if i try as an array element, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular resource:

```
angular.module('portApp').factory('Port', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('ports.json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From another Stack Overflow thread:

```
theApp.factory('mainInfo', function($http) { 

    var obj = {content:null};

    $http.get('content.json').success(function(data) {
        // you can do some processing here
        obj.content = data;
    });    

    return obj;    
});
```

You can see it here:

[AngularJS: factory $http.get JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `function` keyword in the `$http.get` and also the wrong variable name

```
$http.get('ports.json').then(function(res) { // <--- THIS
    var works = res.data;
});
```