# Access HTTP GET JSON property in angular controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using a factory in angular.js and $http.get method to grab and process JSON data. The JSON data seems successfully parsed into factory, but I have problem access property of this JSON data.

Here is my js code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);      

app.factory('mainInfo', function($http) { 

    var obj = {content:null};
    //the php will return json data below
    $http.get('http://localhost/test.php').success(function(response){ 
        obj.content = response.records;

    });    

    return obj;    
});


app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, mainInfo){
    $scope.foo = mainInfo.content;
}) ;
```

Now if I try to access foo within `Ctrl` controller, the webpage will display no data:
`<div ng-controller="Ctrl">Controller: {{foo}}</div>`
However, if I change to `$scope.foo = mainInfo` in the `Ctrl`, then the webpage will display correctly the JSON data.

**May I know what is the proper way to access `mainInfo.content` property in `Ctrl` controller?**

The reason why I need to access JSON property is because I need to pre-process the data. I intend to use these data in a Chart, as in below controller. Currently this controller is not working either, because I have the same problem accessing JSON property as in the `Ctrl` controller.

```
app.controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope, mainInfo) {
    var timePoints = [];
    var percentagePoints = [];
    var i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < mainInfo.content.length; i ++) {
        timePoints.push(mainInfo.content[i].Time);
        percentagePoints.push(mainInfo.content[i].Percentage);
    }

    $scope.labels = timePoints;

    $scope.data = percentagePoints;

    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
});
```

The json data:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Time": "2015-07-25 08:00:00",
        "Percentage": "60"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Time": "2015-07-25 09:00:00",
        "Percentage": "70"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Time": "2015-07-25 10:00:00",
        "Percentage": "80"
    }
    ]
}
```

With regards to the factory-controller communication, I am just referring the solution from another post: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931623/3701346)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$http.get returns a promise -- your problem is that you are returning "obj" immediately, and your controller tries to access the data before the $http.get promise is resolved.

use $http like so (no need to use $q.defer() as shown in the other comment):

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);      

app.factory('mainInfo', function($http) { 
    var getRecordsPromise = $http.get('http://localhost/test.php').then(function(response){ 
        //whatever is returned here will be accessible in the .then that is chained
        return response.data.records;
    });    

    return {
        getRecords: getRecordsPromise
    };    
});


app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, mainInfo){
    mainInfo.getRecords.then(function (records) {
        $scope.foo = records;
    });
}) ;
```

Comment: That's actually not the problem at all. OP is trying to maintain data inside their factory. You'll notice they said it works fine if the use `$scope.foo = mainInfo`. The problem is due to JavaScript references

Comment: $scope.foo = mainInfo sets the scope object to the same object returned by the factory -- when you do this, changes to the object's properties will be reflected in the template once mainInfo.content (or $scope.foo.content, same reference) is set. However, this does not change that the controller is setting the value before the promise has resolved if you do not chain to the $http.get promise. 

If the Factory were to return a primitive value instead of an object, you will face the same problem if you do not use the promise

Comment: If you check the post referenced by the OP, it offers the same two options -- returning an object whose data will be set later (as in the OP), or returning the $http promise itself. Also, the question was specifically "What is the proper way to access this data in the controller?" The only answer is to use a promise -- having the factory return an object whose data will be set later is fine for templating purposes but to execute code in the controller on the data you should chain to the $http.get promise

Comment: Hmm, fair point but it's not the only answer. You can have the best of both worlds; see my update

Comment: Also, I don't think `success` is chainable, ie the return value from `success` isn't passed into chained `then` calls. Better to use `then` and just unwrap `response.data`

Comment: You are right about chaining to success not being proper here, though it is chainable. It returns the original promise and not a new promise so the ".then" chained will get the original response and not the value returned by .success -- I overlooked this, and have made the appropriate edit.

Comment: Note that the data inside the factory will already persist and be accessible  via mainInfo.getRecords, which will be a resolved promise when accessed by other modules in the future

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
var obj = {content: []};
obj.$promise = $http.get('http://localhost/test.php').then(function(response) {
    angular.copy(response.data.records, obj.content);
    return response.data;
});
return obj;
```

The reason your former method didn't work was because you were re-assigning the `content` property of `obj`, thus destroying any previous references.

This is also why using `$scope.foo = mainInfo` worked because the reference to `obj` (via `mainInfo`) was maintained.

Using [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) maintains the previous reference whilst populating the data.

---

That should take care of references in the template that get updated when the `$http` promise resolves (due to `$http` triggering a *digest* cycle). For accessing the data in your controller, use the `$promise` property

```
$scope.foo = mainInfo.content;
mainInfo.$promise.then(function(data) {
    // access data.records here
});
```

---

Maintaining the data inside your factory is a good idea if you share your factory with multiple consumers (eg controllers). They may all reference `mainInfo.content` and `mainInfo.$promise` and all will be accessing the same data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);      

app.factory('mainInfo', function($http) { 
    return {
        getData: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();


            //the php will return json data below
            $http.get('http://localhost/test.php').success(function(response){ 
                deferred.resolve(response.records);});



            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});


app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, mainInfo){
    mainInfo.getData().then(function(result) {
        $scope.foo = result.content;
    });
}) ;
```

Comment: Ah, the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) rears its ugly head once again

Comment: I agree that in this case, I should just have chained the $http promise... My mistake. However, I tend to find this pattern useful in many cases where I prefer to do my error handling  or processing of the data in the services instead of each individual controller that consumes the service. Doesn't seem to me like the reasons for it being an anti-pattern outweigh the DRY-ability it provides in those cases.

Comment: @GPicazo that's why promise chaining is so effective. You can handle errors, transformations, further requests, etc all in your services and just return a promise in the end. You don't have to use a deferred object when you already have a promise

Comment: @GPicazo you can return inside the chained .then to process data/handling error. For example in your post just replace `deferred.resolve(response.records);` with `return response.records;`