# Output page blank while fetching data from JSON file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I have just started learning angularjs, I'm trying to load data from my json file on view. json file has a list of houses. But does not get showed on my view when I load the index.html file.

**Data.json**

```
      [
{
    "type": "Condo",
    "price": 220000,
    "address": "213 Grove Street",
    "description": "Excellent place! Really nice view!"
},
{
    "type": "House",
    "price": 410500,
    "address": "7823 Winding Way",
    "description": "Beautiful home with lots of space for large family."
},
{
    "type": "Duplex",
    "price": 395000,
    "address": "834 River Lane",
    "description": "Great neighourhood and lot's of nice green space."
},


]
```

**cribsFactory.js**

```
    angular
   .module('ngCribs')
   .factory('cribsFactory', function($http) {

    function getCribs() {

        return $http.get('data/data.json');
    }

    return {
        getCribs: getCribs
    }
     });
```

**cribsController.js**

```
     angular
       .module('ngCribs')
       .controller('cribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory) {

   $scope.cribs;

   cribsFactory.getCribs().success(function(data) {
        $scope.cribs = data;
    }).error(function(error) {
       console.log(error);
   });

    });
```

**index.html**

```
       <!doctype html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ng-cribbs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
            <div class="well" ng-repeat="crib in cribs">
                <h3>{{ crib.address }}</h3>
                <p>
                    <strong>Type: </strong>{{ crib.type }}</p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Description: </strong>{{ crib.description }}</p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Price: </strong>{{ crib.price | currency }}</p>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"/>
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"/>
    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"/>
</script>
<script src="app.js"/>
</script>
<script src="scripts/cribsController.js"/>
 </script>
 <script src="scripts/cribsFactory.js"/>
  </script>
  </html>
```

I'm trying to run the above code in htdocs folder of XAMPP. The folder structure is in the screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot]

The json file is inside the data folder and the files cribsFactory.js & cribsController.js are in scripts folder. When i type the URL "http://localhost/ng-cribbs/" in Firefox the output is a completely blank page with no error message of any sort hence the difficulty in debugging.

I was able to load data using an array but facing problem while using JSON file.. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: factory $http.get JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file)

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I have edited my question for your reference.. Please have a look..

Comment: According to the screen shot you posted, your data.json is in the same level as the data folder. Wasn't data.json supposed to be under the data folder?

Comment: @Jodevan I put it there after the json file inside data folder did not generate any output.

Comment: have you tried the url as `../data/data.json`, instead of just `data/data.json`?

Comment: @RobWilson Yes tried it but still nothing. Just a blank page..

Comment: Have you tried moving the json file into the same folder as the scripts (as a test), to get around the same domain issue that @Ankh mentions? (change the url to be just `data.json`).  Also, are you able to see the request going out on the network tab of the browser's dev tools; is there a response with the data?

Comment: How about don't initialize `$scope.cribs;` above the factory service? What that mean is delete the `$scope.cribs;`.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin The error was due to invalid JSON. After I validated it the correct output was being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json data was not valid, validate any json data before and you can use the below corrected json. Hope it helps! [validate json here](http://jsonlint.com)

```
     [{
    "type": "Condo",
    "price": 220000,
    "address": "213 Grove Street",
    "description": "Excellent place! Really nice view!"
  }, {
    "type": "House",
    "price": 410500,
    "address": "7823 Winding Way",
    "description": "Beautiful home with lots of space for large family."
  }, {
    "type": "Duplex",
    "price": 395000,
    "address": "834 River Lane",
    "description": "Great neighourhood and lot's of nice green space."
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! It seems that the comma before the closing square bracket was causing problem. After I removed it I'm getting the output correctly..

Comment: Yes that trailing comma caused all problem! Rest everything is cool with code.

Answer (score -1):

Your http call gives you a json string, you should convert it to a javascript array like so: $scope.cribs = JSON.parse(data)

Comment: I just see, the data.json above is not valid json, the last , is wrong, but maybe this is just an extract of your original data file.

Comment: @GuenterGuckelsberger The error was indeed due to invalid JSON. Extra comma after the closing square bracket was causing the error. Removing it solved the problem..