# angularjs $scope in json load in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, controller

I am looking to my json store that contains "$ scope" not initilaliser in an external file. Enssuite to load it into a controller. An example of json file.

```
$scope.templates = {"webapp": {
              "DC01": [   
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 1A",
                          "value": "0",
                          "selected": "selected",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC01_GF1_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC01_GF1_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF1_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF1_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC01_GF1_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC01_GF1_CPUMP1,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC01_GF1_CPUMP2,
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF1_D_POMP1A1,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF1_D_POMP2A1,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC01_P_GF1_DEB
                                  },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 3A",
                          "value": "1",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC01_GF3_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC01_GF3_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF3_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF3_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC01_GF3_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC01_GF3_CPUMP1,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC01_GF3_CPUMP2,
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF3_D_POMP1A2,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF3_D_POMP2A2,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC01_P_GF3_DEB
                                  },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 4B",
                          "value": "2",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC01_GF4_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC01_GF4_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF4_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF4_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC01_GF4_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC01_GF4_CPUMP1,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC01_GF4_CPUMP2,                                        
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF4_D_POMP1B1,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF4_D_POMP2B1,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC01_P_GF4_DEB                                      
                                  },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 6B",
                          "value": "3",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC01_GF6_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC01_GF6_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF6_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC01_GF6_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC01_GF6_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC01_GF6_CPUMP1,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC01_GF6_CPUMP2,                                        
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF6_D_POMP1B2,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC01_P_GF6_D_POMP2B2,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC01_P_GF6_DEB                                        
                                  },
                        }
                      ],
              "DC02": [
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 1A",
                          "value": "0",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC02_GF1_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC02_GF1_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF1_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF1_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC02_GF1_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF1_RM,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF1_RM,                                          
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF1_DF,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF1_DF,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC02_DEBIT_GF1
                                  },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 2A",
                          "value": "1",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC02_GF2_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC02_GF2_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF2_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF2_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC02_GF2_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF2_RM,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF2_RM,  
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF2_DF,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF2_DF,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC02_DEBIT_GF2                                     
                                 },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 4B",
                          "value": "2",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC02_GF4_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC02_GF4_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF4_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF4_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC02_GF4_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF4_RM,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF4_RM,                                          
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF4_DF,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF4_DF,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC02_DEBIT_GF4                                        
                                  },
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Groupe Froid 5B",
                          "value": "3",
                          "data": {
                                    "status"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_STATUS,
                                    "capacite"          : $scope.DC02_GF5_CAP_T,
                                    "alarm"             : $scope.DC02_GF5_ALM,
                                    "tmpEntreeEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF5_TMP_EE,    
                                    "tmpSortieEG"       : $scope.DC02_GF5_TMP_SE,
                                    "alarm1"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_CURR_ALARM1, 
                                    "alarm2"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_CURR_ALARM2,
                                    "alarm3"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_CURR_ALARM3,
                                    "alarm4"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_CURR_ALARM4,
                                    "alarm5"            : $scope.DC02_GF5_CURR_ALARM5,
                                    "etatPompe1"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF5_RM,
                                    "etatPompe2"        : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF5_RM,                                          
                                    "alarmPompe1"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMA_GF5_DF,
                                    "alarmPompe2"       : $scope.DC02_CVC_PMB_GF5_DF,
                                    "debit"             : $scope.DC02_DEBIT_GF5                                        
                                  },
                        }
                      ],
              }};
```

it is possible to store this json in an external file or a service?

Thank you for the help provided.

Comment: yes you can store

Comment: yes..create a service and return this json from one of its methods..and then inject the service in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you give me an example I debute on angularrjs. Thank you

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your $scope definition is not static (i.e. it has references to some $scope variables as well), the possible way to achieve what you want is to:
1) define your scope constructing method in some file like:

```
function createMyScope($scope){
$scope.template = .....
};
```

This method takes scope reference as a parameter and modifies it.
Later you can use it in your controller as:

```
app.controller('test', function('$scope') {
   createMyScope($scope) ;
....
```

You can wrap the scope creator method to be part of some anjular constant or service if you want.